# Installing two smart Alexa powered switches

Tags: electrical, neutral, smart-switch

I am installing two new smart Eaton WFSW15-C2 smart switches.  I have a new house, so it has the neutral wires required for a switch that requires the four wires.  The two I am replacing are standard three-wire.

One problem is there are 4 neutral wires and they are all bundled up together under one red wire nut and the original switches have two black wires and the ground.  Using a tester I was able to tell the hot.  I guess the other black wire would be the load and goes to the outside light.

The biggest question I have is this:

Since I have a box with three switches and 4 neutral wires, should I use two of the neutral wires, one for each switch, and leave the other two twisted together and one to each of the new smart switches?

Answer (score 3):

You have 1 neutral "in" and 3 "out". They aren't "spares". What you need to do here is to **add** the switch neutrals. You will likely need either a single new large wire nut or split into two but all connected together. If you need extra pieces of **white** wire, you can either buy some wire or pull some out if a cable. Should be 12 AWG for a 20A circuit, 12 or 14 for a 15A circuit. (You can't use black, green, bare copper or any other color except white or gray.)

You will have a total of **seven** neutrals:

- 1 in from panel
- 3 out to fixtures
- 3 switches

They all need to connect together. So you can:

- Use a single wire nut - *if you can find one rated to handle 7 wires*
- Use two wire nuts - since this needs a wire to connect them together, you will effectively have *nine* wires, so one with 3 + wire to the other one, one with 4 + wire to the other one.
- Use three wire nuts - which then means 10 altogether - one with 3 + wire to another one, one with 3 + wire to another one and one with 1 + wires from the other 2. This is, in some ways, the most logical: Panel + 2 groups; group of switches; group of fixtures. But really "whatever works".

Beware that switch boxes can get crowded. A typical smart switch is a bit deeper than a simple toggle switch, so it takes more room in the box. The extra wire nut(s) will take more room. So it may be a tight fit by the time you are done.

Comment: So with the four neutrals, I can split them into two, and then run a separate neutral copper wire from the two bundles into each of the two new smart switches?

Comment: But that they should remain wrapped together either in 4 bundle or two bundles of two with two wires coming from the neutral bundles to the switches?

Comment: So effectively I will have two neutrals wrapped with a third copper wire going to the switch, well this times two!

Comment: @DanielK. Yes.  The general idea is if you can't fit all the wires under 1 wire nut, to split them into 2 wire nuts, including a jumper wire between the 2 nuts so they are ALL connected.  They also sell push-in connectors that take up to 8 wires.  Some wire nuts say they are good for 6 wires, but I don't like using nuts very near the limits of their capacity,  and I'm good at it.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I had to do.  I used to do electrical back in the day, the early 90s and it's been a while.  I had to create two separate bundles of two neutral wires with one wire as a jumper between the two bundles and one wire running from each neutral bundle to the proper switches.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: @DanielK "with a third copper wire going to the switch" - just be 100% certain that it is not a _bare_ copper wire! Bare wire can _only_ be used for ground. Also, since you're dealing with the neutral, it _must_ be white or grey as manassehkats mentioned in his answer.